# How to make the transition to the desired composer in one scene by pressing a button

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegraf.js

I have a scene

```
const chooseScene = new Scenes.WizardScene(
  "chooseDateWizard",
  pickDate,
  checkDate,
  messenger,
  backOrQuantityNight,
  fullName,
  phone,
  checkData,
  details,
  paid
);
```

I need to go from composer backOrQuantityNight to composer checkDate when I click the back button, i.e. to make a transition to a specific composer.

```
backOrQuantityNight.hears("Back", async (ctx) => {
conversion code
});
```

the compassers go one at a time with the command return ctx.wizard.next();

compser example:

```
const pickDate = new Composer();
pickDate.on("text", async (ctx) => {
  ctx.wizard.state.data = {};
  await ctx.reply("write the date");
  return ctx.wizard.next();
});
```

I would like to implement in composers, because in the end of the scene I record the data that the user entered in the database. but maybe there is another solution, that is somehow rewrite the code, so I will accept any answer to solve this problem